# Symfony / Sonata Admin: List form on Edit form

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I have a one (category) to many (product) relationship set up, and I'd like to have a list of products show up at the bottom of the edit category page.

It seems like this would be a common thing to do, but I haven't found any way to do it (or any examples of it).  I have managed to get the product to display using sonata_type_collection but that gives me a whole edit form for the Product, when I really just want a list of products associated with the category.

Two questions here, really:

Is this possible?

Is it discouraged (which would explain the lack of examples)?  If so, why?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "have a list of products" ? Is this general information irrelevant to the form you are submitting or input for the category you are editing?

Comment: The info isn't relevant to the submission of the form, but I want to provide direct links to the relevant products at the bottom of a category detail page.  E.g. if the category is iPhone, then I'd like to have a list of iPhone products at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to do what you are looking for is overriding the edit template. At your admin serivce declaration you can do so:

```
services:
    sonata.admin.mail:
        class: %sonata.admin.category.class%
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Categories", label: "Category" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - %skooli.category.class%
            - ~
        calls:
            - [ setTemplate, ["edit", "AcmeAdminBundle:CategoryAdmin:edit.html.twig"] ]
```

Then, under `AcmeBundle/Resources/views/CategoryAdmin/edit.html.twig` you can have something like this:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}
{# Override any block from the parent view if necessary #}
{% block products %}
    <ul>
    {% for product in object.products%}
        <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock products %}
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it's very close to what I'm trying to do.  The only problem I'm having is that I currently have 

`->add('product','sonata_type_collection', array(
                    'type_options' => array(
                        'delete' => false,
                        'read_only' => true,
                        'btn_add' => false,
                    )
            ))`
in my CategoryAdmin.php configureFormFields function, and despite trying a few different variations, I can't find anything that'll cause it to pull in that new custom template.

Comment: The template is related to your Category Admin not your Product Admin

Comment: The template is at Resources/views/CategoryAdmin/edit.html.twig, and in my services.yml I have sonata.admin.category:....

But in CategoryAdmin.php in configureFormFields I have the chained calls to add() that determine what shows up in the edit form.  If I don't put anything related to 'product' in there, the form renders without the list I was hoping for, and all of the attempts I've made to include an add() for products hasn't panned out.  

This is my first attempt at a custom template, so I might be missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Are you trying to create a Category or Edit an existing Category which you know for sure that has been related to some Products?

Comment: I'm trying to edit an existing Category, which has Products associated with it.  I'd like to have all of those products show up in a list at the bottom of the page.

See this example I cobbled together: http://i.imgur.com/wZv2qpu.jpg

Comment: I never did get this working, and have given up for now, but I'm accepting this answer because I'm convinced that this is what I'd have to do to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

In your original question you were talking about the *edit* template of the category. In your comment you want the list to appear in the *show* action.
The latter is easy. As soon as you add your relation to your showFields action they will be shown:

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class CategoryAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->add('products')
        ;    
    }
}
```

If you don't like the look you can create a custom template. This will work for *show* and *edit*:
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_show.html#setting-up-a-custom-show-template-very-useful

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and apologies for the imprecise wording.  What I'm looking for is a list of relevant Products when I view the edit screen for a given category (e.g. foobar.com/bundle/category/1234/edit).

Comment: That sounds like strange request since most of the time you want to inline edit child entities instead of only showing them. But you can use a custom edit template then.

Comment: Inline editing of child entities is a possibility down the road, but for now I'd just like to have a coherent representation of them.  The default display is the entire editform for all Products associated with the Category, and this is definitely not what I'm looking for.

I think overriding the template is what I need to do, but so far I haven't been able to get that to work. This seems to be close: http://php-jotter.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/override-display-of-sonatacollectiontyp.html but it's not working as-is, and I don't have the knowledge to tweak it.

Comment: I now have a similar task. I need to show the list view of existing items in the edit form for a new item. I just realized that you can use blocks that were meant for the dashboard page on every template - even the edit template. I will post a gist example soon!

Comment: Thanks @webDEVILopers - I'd love to see that gist when it's done.

Comment: This is my "Recent Contracts" custom list view example so far: https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/11520ffd82d762c4ca72 - Still have to find out how to pass parameters to the execute method in order to pass a categoryId for instance. @MattBoutet

Comment: And this is a nice example for using a ProductId resp. CategoryId: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ronanguilloux/0676257355c3e6bf3005/raw/837f76cdc112c7c46c1a4eb7ff2b79276a6bf41c/ProductBlockService.php